# How to take a print out of a html table using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have a table in a PHP page. It is a invoice. 
So I want to print it after adding items to it, 
and I had already done the coding part and all the things are working properly.

Now I just want to print that invoice table to a paper
 by pressing a button. I searched on Google but no clue is found to do that.

Can any one help me?

This is my table on right hand side. It is populated by the form in left hand side
so I just want to print that right hand side table:

[image]

Comment: print where? user computer? server printer?

Comment: There is nothing to do on server side so no need of php. You can do with JS. if you need more details in JS, add JS in tags.

Comment: @Dagon-yep i want to print in user computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

Add an attribute `id` to your table `your_content`

Place an anchor tag :

```
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="printPage">Print</a>
```

And add script:

*This script will initially show print preview of the content that is inside your table.*

```
 <script lang='javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#printPage').click(function(){
        var data = '<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">';           
        data += '<div id="div_print">';
        data += $('#your_content').html();
        data += '</div>';

        myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
    });
 });
```

Copy the script part and put it on the top of your page. And put the print link, [above anchor tag] wherever you want. And make sure you have included the jquery script file.

Comment: Thanks i will try this one and let you know. 
and i will try to add a print screen of my table

Comment: @K u s H- i tried to do using this code. but i don't know where to put these code. 
data += '<div id="div_print">';
        data += $('#your_content').html();
        data += '</div>';

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery some something as simple as this. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This would be too trivial of a situation for something like jQuery so you should use plain Javascript to do it. Place this somewhere on your page and see if it works:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printPage();">Print</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 function printPage(){
        var tableData = '<table border="1">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML+'</table>';
        var data = '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>'+tableData;       
        myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
    };
 </script>​​​​​​
```

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pxqtb/

Answer (score 2):

i used this code and it solved my problem. thank you all for helping me.....

```
function printlayout() {
     var data = '<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">';           
       var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('printlayout');
        //data += $('printlayoutable').html();
        //data += '</div>';
var WindowObject = window.open('', "TrackHistoryData", 
                              "width=740,height=325,top=200,left=250,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=no");           
 WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
  //WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. (1) If you create a new HTML page with just the invoice, the user can print that page using the browser's print capacity. (2) Alternatively, you can allow the user to download an invoice document which you create and print that. (3) You can use the JavaScript command `window.print();` in conjunction with #1. Have a look at [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml).